# python requests streaming not working with django streaminghttpresponse

Tags: python, django, http, python-requests

I have a simple django app (that is acting as the server) where I'm trying to stream the response to the client (requests is the client). Here is the views.py for the django app.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, StreamingHttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.http import condition

import time

@condition(etag_func=None)
def stream_response(request):
    resp = StreamingHttpResponse( stream_response_generator() )
    return resp

def stream_response_generator():
    # yield "<html><body>\n"
    for x in range(1,5):
        yield "<div>%s</div>\n" % x
        print "test %s" % x
        #yield " " * 1024  # Encourage browser to render incrementally
        time.sleep(1)
    # yield "</body></html>\n"
```

I am using the StreamingHttpResponse function in django to delay some data sent to whoever requests it. Below is my client.py.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/stream', stream=True)
for line in r.iter_lines():
    # filter out keep-alive new lines
    if line:
        print line
```

Whenever the client requests the url, it doesn't display the output in increments. It displays the whole message at once after it downloads everything. And when I uncomment the `yield "" * 1024`, it only shows the first `<div>1</div>`. Do I need to change something in the headers for my views.py so requests knows how to stream the data? When I use curl to access the url, it streams the response successfully.

Comment: I run the script as you said, when I uncomment the yield "" * 1024, I still get 4 <div></div> element.

Comment: Hey @Aison, do you get them with a delay in between them? I just copied the response from sublime text 2, and it turns out that the other divs are invisible to me. When I copy and paste into another editor, they actually appear.

Comment: Hey @Aison turns out it was right the whole time. Sublime text 2 was not showing the other divs.

Comment: I'm not sure the problem is about Sublime, maybe you could change yield " " * 1024 to yield " " 10 and see what happen.